# Copy versioned file to other directory

Tags: powershell

I want to find in directory file `example-file-5.0.0.0.jar` and copy renamed it to another directory. I have written this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryFrom | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "example-file-\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.jar$" } | Copy-Item -Destination $directory\"example-file.jar -Recurse -Force
```

The problem is that, I have another file named `example-file-5.0.0.0-debug.jar` in same directory and it is copied instead of `example-file-5.0.0.0.jar` file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something else. Your `-match` is *right*:

```
"example-file-5.0.0.0-debug.jar" -match "example-file-\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.jar$"
# Output: False
"example-file-5.0.0.0.jar" -match "example-file-\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.jar$"
# Output: True
```

However, your `Copy-Item` cmdlet has a random quote inside the destination and misses a closing quote. I would recommend you to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet so you don't have to worry about a trailing slash:

```
Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path $directory "example-file.jar") -Force
```

**Note:** I also removed the `-recurse` parameter since you are copy a *single* file.